# Moving Jar files to Referenced Library

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, m2eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE for writing my codes. I have added jar files using POM.xml file. Everything was installed correctly but all the jar files are not stored in Referenced Library folder they are stored under JRE System Library.

Can some one please help me in moving them on to Referenced Library Folder.

[image]

Comment: It is hard to give advice without seeing your pom.xml. From the image it looks as if the referenced libraries are not stored **under** the JRE system library but **next to it**. How did you include the libraries? Is your project type a Java project (in this case the libs would look OK) or a Maven project?

Comment: Also please include the `.classpath` and `.project` files.

Comment: Furthermore, what is it that you're trying to accomplish? **Referenced Libraries** and **JRE System Library** are not physical folders; they're just logical representations of how the dependencies are configured.